# How to retrieve Images using Parse Linq query ..?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, parse-platform

I want to retrieve  Images From parse object Using linq query

```
// Upload Photo to Parse
private async void UploadPhotoBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ParseFile img = new ParseFile("picture.png", UserPhoto);
    var photo = new ParseObject("photo");
    photo["Photo"] = img;
    await photo.SaveAsync();
}

// Query to retrieve 
private async void return_photo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var query = from photo in ParseObject.GetQuery("photo")
                orderby photo.CreatedAt descending
                select photo;
    IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = await query.FindAsync();
    foreach (var photo in results)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: and what happen with your current code? any exception, or it returns different data from what you expect? if the latter, what it currently returns and what you expect it to returns?

Comment: how i can convert results of query to image ..?

Comment: this code doesn't working ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not experienced using `parse.com` .NET API in anyway. So, just an idea I get after looking at some online resources about the API, have you tried to get image from query this way? :

```
foreach (var photo in results)
{
    ParseFile img = photo.Get<ParseFile>("Photo");
    //then try to use img.Url to display the image
}
```